# Get URL from UIWebView after redirect

Tags: uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

My app writes out a small HTML file to the user's temporary cache. This file points to the our login in server, and contains the user name and password and a redirect to the actual URL I want the user to go to.

Everything works OK but within the methods of the UIWebView I need to detect what URL I eventually end up on because I must parse this URL to determine whether to show or hide navigation.

Everything works BUT I cannot detect the actual URL that the page ends up on - I just keep getting the filePath.

My header is as so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerApprovals : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSURLRequest *currentRequest;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *requestType;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *pathToFile;

@end
```

And my implementation file:

```
#import "ViewControllerApprovals.h"
#import "ContactsDatabase.h"
#import "UserDefaults.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface ViewControllerApprovals ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerApprovals

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  self.view.backgroundColor =
      [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sos.png"]];

  if (self) {
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
  self.webView.delegate = self;

  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pathToFile];
  NSURLRequest *tmpRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
 [self.webView loadRequest:tmpRequest];

}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  self.currentRequest = request;
  [self hideNavigationBar:request];
  return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Hide Navigation Bar
- (void)hideNavigationBar:(NSURLRequest *)pRequest {

  NSString *currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

  NSURL *url = pRequest.URL;
  NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
  NSString *nsfURL = @"#approvalPage";

  if ([urlString rangeOfString:nsfURL].location == NSNotFound) {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE animated:YES];
  } else {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:YES];
  }
}

@end
```